# Typed library - elements of the same class

Tags: jquery, typed.js

In short, I add elements of the same class via append and then I want to animate them using typed.js. I wrote a little feature for this, unfortunately it is a problem with it. Every previous string is looping and in a circle animates the same effect. How can I change this?

This libary: http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/

```js
function animateConsole(string) {
  $("#console-content").append('<p class="bash-line"></p>');
    $(".bash-line").each(function() {
      var typed = new Typed(this, {
      strings: [string],
      typeSpeed: 10,
      showCursor: false,
    });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function) {

  setTimeout(function() {animateConsole('<span>//</span>GET CONNECTION SECRET');}, 3500);
  setTimeout(function() {animateConsole('<span>//</span>SENDING REQUEST');}, 4500);
  setTimeout(function() {animateConsole('<span>//</span>WAITING FOR RESPONSE');}, 6500);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="console-content"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `$(".bash-line").each(` targets all the `.bash-line` elements (*even the previously appended ones*)

So you need to keep a reference of the one you just created and use that when initializing the `Typed` plugin.

```js
function animateConsole(string) {
  var bash = $('<p class="bash-line"></p>');
  
  $("#console-content").append(bash);
  var typed = new Typed(bash.get(0), {
      strings: [string],
      typeSpeed: 10,
      showCursor: false,
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  setTimeout(function() {animateConsole('<span>//</span>GET CONNECTION SECRET');}, 3500);
  setTimeout(function() {animateConsole('<span>//</span>SENDING REQUEST');}, 4500);
  setTimeout(function() {animateConsole('<span>//</span>WAITING FOR RESPONSE');}, 6500);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.6/lib/typed.min.js"></script>

<div id="console-content"></div>
```